# Jacoco enforce maximum allowed cyclomatic complexity

Tags: jacoco-plugin

I was wondering if there is a way to enforce maximum method cyclomatic complexity with jacoco maven/gradle?
(eg.: fail build if any method in the bundle has a CC above 10?)